# If elif else not working1

Tags: python

```
def scene3():
    print("After you defeated the Giant Spider you encounter a Dark Dragon do you want to Attack or Run:? ")
    encounter = input("Do you want to attack the Dragon?: [Attack/Run]")

    if encounter.strip().lower() == "Attack":
        print("You Attack the Dark Dragon and DIED apparently this rare monster is to much for you game over")
        quit()

    elif encounter.strip().lower() =="Run":
        print("You successfully outrun the Dark Dragon and landed in a Capital City in Magical World")
        time.sleep(delay2)
```

output:

```
After you defeated the Giant Spider you encounter a Dark Dragon do you want to Attack or Run:? 
Do you want to attack the Dragon?: [Attack/Run]run

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You lower case a string and then check against strings with upper case. Try changinge "Attack" to "attack" and etc.

Comment: Well, yes, because "attack" exits the program.  Right?

Comment: Just do `encounter = encounter.strip().lower()` once, then compare `encounter` to `"attack"` and `"run"`, etc.

Comment: Another hint: According to Pythons documentation [`quit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit) is useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `if` and `else` condition should check for string with `lowercase` when using `lower.()`.

Please change the code to this:

```
import time

delay2 = 5

def scene3():
    print("After you defeated the Giant Spider you encounter a Dark Dragon do you want to Attack or Run:? ")
    encounter = input("Do you want to attack the Dragon?: [Attack/Run]")

    if encounter.strip().lower() == "attack":
        print("You Attack the Dark Dragon and DIED apparently this rare monster is to much for you game over")
        quit()

    elif encounter.strip().lower() == "run":
        print("You successfully outrun the Dark Dragon and landed in a Capital City in Magical World")
        time.sleep(delay2)

scene3()
```

O/P:

```
$ python3 test.py
After you defeated the Giant Spider you encounter a Dark Dragon do you want to Attack or Run:?
Do you want to attack the Dragon?: [Attack/Run]attack
You Attack the Dark Dragon and DIED apparently this rare monster is to much for you game over

$ python3 test.py
After you defeated the Giant Spider you encounter a Dark Dragon do you want to Attack or Run:?
Do you want to attack the Dragon?: [Attack/Run]run
You successfully outrun the Dark Dragon and landed in a Capital City in Magical World
```

Comment: Thank you so much it also solves my problem i need to change the string in lower case "Attack" - "attack" Thank you.

Comment: Please read [answer] and don't answer questions that boil down to simple typos, as they are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).